# Get a page URL using only the Slug?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, slug

Wondered what the best approach would be to get the url for a given entry page using only a slug for reference? I imagined it being something like this:

```
 public function getPageURL($slug) {
    $page = craft()->elements->slug($slug);
    @return getURL($page);
  }
```

Usage example:

```
<a href="{{ craft.PLUGINNAME.getPageURL("staff") }}">Staff</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely untested, but something like this should work:

```
public function getPageUrl($slug)
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->slug = $slug;
    $entry = $criteria->first();

    if ($entry)
    {
        return UrlHelper::getUrl($entry->uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Brad, that's the second time you've pointed me in the direction of the Helpers. http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference#craft.app.helpers

Comment: You can even simplify that by just invoking the `getUrl()` method on the `$entry` object. There's no need for calling the `UrlHelper` (the `getUrl()` method is already using it). So, you can shorten the last line to this:
`return $entry->getUrl();`